# Can someone help me to understand in Python print(4 & 3)-->0 and print(5 & 4)--> 4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone help me to understand in Python 
print(4 & 3)-->0 
and 
print(5 & 4)--> 4?

Comment: The `&` operator is also called the `Bitwise AND operator`.

Comment: `&` is the bitwise AND

Comment: Do you understand what `&` does? if not, just read about it: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` operation is a bitwise ANDing each pair of corresponding bits:

- 4 & 3 == b100 & b011 == b000 = 0
- 5 & 4 == b101 & b100 == b100 = 4